# Calculate future service dates

Tags: vba, excel

I have been working on a VBA Macro that takes vehicle service and MOT dates from a data entry page inserts them into a new line on a different sheet and calculates future service dates on a set interval time I have entered. This all works fine its just the next part I am having trouble with. I then need to take these dates and add them into a schedule.

I have tried setting up nested `Do While` loops but I can't get it working. I've made a simplified example of what I am trying to do (link below).

Red is the manually entered data. Yellow is the 1st macro product with the new line containing copied dates with orange calculated future dates. Green is the new line inserted (where I have got to) but I need the symbols inserted into that new row.

[image]

This is the basic code I have have for entering the service dates into the schedule from the database.

```
x = 1
y = x + 1
z = 16
'my data starts in C6R16 and I have 5 dates (hence to 21)
Do While z < 21
'Have a shedule for the whole year so 53.
    Do While x < 53
'If functions to locate which week the event is located
    If Worksheets("Dates Input").Cells(6, z).Value > Worksheets("Maintenance Shedule").Cells(3, x) Then
        If Worksheets("Dates Input").Cells(6, z).Value < Worksheets("Maintenance Shedule").Cells(3, y) Then
'Quick location of the lowest empy cell. The others will be full of data from prevous entries.
                Range("F9:F10").Select
                Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
                    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
                Loop
'Move my active cell to the correct place
            ActiveCell.Offset(-1, (3 + x)).Select
            ActiveCell = "/"
        Else
        End If
'Move to the next set of dates in shedule
    x = x + 1
    Loop
'move to next service date
z = z + 1
Loop
```

On top of this, I need to add (I assume) an `If` statement to check if there is an MOT (M) and service (/) in the same week so that one does not delete the other.

Any pointers and help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

x and z are counters by one.
I would recommend using

```
For x = 1 To 21
Next
```

instead. This doesn't seem to be your problem though.
<strike>The</strike>

```
Do While Not IsEmpty(~~~~~~)
```

actually means do while the cells are empty.

Comment: Do While Not IsEmpty(~~~~) will continue the loop until it finds an empty cell, which appears to be the OP's intent. I'm not sure what you mean when you are saying it does this while the cells are empty